# check if a method mutates an object

Tags: python, immutability

I am passing a dictionary `{str: object}` into an executable piece of code. Basically calling this: `exec(some_user_defined_code, symbol_dictionary)`. The problem is that I do not know what `some_user_defined_code` is and what it does. All I know is that it is supplied by a user as a string. But what I need is to make sure to keep the existing objects in the dictionary unchanged. In other words, it can add new items to the dictionary, but the objects that are already there should be strictly read-only for the user code.

(Please do not ask me "Why do you need that?"... Well, I kind of need it. It would make my life better because my code will be more error-proof.)

This relates to the concept of immutability which is IMHO rather neglected in Python. Something like constness check performed at C++ compile-time would be nice to have at Python run-time.

It would probably require analyzing the code with ast or symtable modules. Or just the `attr` and `dir` of the class would be sufficient?

However to make my question more focused, I am thinking how to check whether a method of an arbitrary class mutates the self-object or not.

I am trying to figure out how a theoretical function `does_method_mutate_object(class_definition, method_name)` should work. It would need going through the code and apply the following rules if it encounters the following statements:

1) `self.some_member = something` 
   then 'return True' (it does mutate the object)

2) `self.some_other_method(something)` then `return does_method_mutate_object(class_definition, some_other_method_name)` (i.e. recursive check)

3) `some_alias = self` or `some_alias = self.some_member` then check the rules 1 and 2 not only for `self` but also for `some_alias`

4) some other rules? setters etc.

Well, I know it is very likely it is not even possible to achieve. But maybe... anyone has any idea?

Comment: You should also do 4. `x = self.some_other_method`, then check rule 2 not only for `some_other_method` but also for `x`. Now here's the brain teaser. What if you have `x = self.some_mutating_method if some_boolean else self.some_non_mutating_method`? Knowing whether x really mutates or not may only be determinable at run time.

Comment: This looks undecidable to me.

Comment: @ Kevin: As for `x = self.some_mutating_method if some_boolean else self.some_non_mutating_method` ... I did not mean this kind of 'runtime' check, this would be really impossible to check without really running it. In other words, if it can call some_mutating_method then it is mutable. It immutable only and only if it can call only immutable methods.

Comment: couldn't you deep_copy your dict/object and pass the copy to the exec?

Comment: Well, then a question arises - how to make a deep copy of an arbitrary, general Python object. Actually it would be my favorite solution - to make a copy of the mutable objects (or those mutated inside the user script) and pass the immutable (not mutated in the script) ones without copying.

Comment: What's the problem with https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy ?

Is it that you just want to copy the objects the script will mutate?

Comment: This is going to be more-or-less impossible to decide with static analysis. `adict[akey] = avalue`, or `setattr(anobj, anattr, avalue)` - how do you decide if that's OK? Immutability isn't "neglected" in Python (for a start, most of the built-in types are immutable); the strong, dynamic typing is a core design decision. If you want to be absolutely certain that an arbitrary method won't mutate the arguments, pass a copy.

Comment: as a separate issue - why does your method use text to define the user callable - most of the library functions which accept a user callable do so by accepting a function object (either a function, bound method, or a lambda).

Comment: Testing whether a arbitary piece of code - with the potential for all sorts of side effects, or all sorts of extra inputs (other than the arguments you know about) makes changes to an arbitrary piece of data, and then completes in some defined way, sounds very much like the halting problem - which is known to be undecidable.